# Export a function from backend

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js backend named `main.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors());
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/ui/dist'));

let count = "1";

app.get('/count', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ "changed": count });
})

const background = function () {
  setTimeout(background, 5000);
  count++;
}

function saveFile () { console.log('entered here') }
// Same behavior when doing:
// const saveFile = function () { console.log('saved') }

background();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`MESS (Mongo Event Sourcing) listening at http://localhost:3000`);
});

exports.saveFile = saveFile
// Same behavior when using 
// module.exports = { saveFile }
```

I wanted to export a function for use in my frontend (Vue).

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { saveFile } from '../main.js'

//...
mounted: async function () {
    await this.loadCount();
  },
  methods: {
    loadCount: async function () {

      let result = await axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_APIURL}count`);
      this.count = result.data.changed;
      setTimeout(this.loadCount, 3000);

      saveFile()
    }
  }
}
```

Now my problem is, I am getting an error stating `"export 'saveFile' was not found in '../main.js'`

And on my browser's dev console, I see another error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

How can I use `saveFile()` from `main.js`?

Comment: `module.exports = { saveFile }`? Keep in mind that anything run by your frontend app runs in the user's browser so unless `saveFile` is purely functional with no side-effects, it probably won't work in both environments

Comment: @Phil - I updated my post to also mention that the behavior is the same when I use ```module.exports = { saveFile }```.. Currently I only have a ```console.log()``` inside the ```saveFile``` function